# compile from source code

Tags: linux, installation

I am trying to follow the 2 steps mentioned below:

1) Downloaded source code of

https://sourceforge.net/projects/hunspell/files/Hyphen/2.8/hyphen-2.8.8.tar.gz/download

2) Compiled it and you will get binary named example:

> hyphen-2.8.8$ ./example ~/dev/smc/hyphenation/hi_IN/hyph_hi_IN.dic
>   ~/hi_sample.text

I have downloaded and uncompressed the tar file. My question is how to compile it?

I am getting this error:

```
[root@ip-172-31-12-85 hyphen-2.8.8]# ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/tmp/santosh/hyphen-2.8.8':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details
```

I was able to resolve the error mentioned above. But I am getting another error in the next step:

```
# make

mv -f .deps/example.Tpo .deps/example.Po
/bin/bash ./libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -g -O2   -o example example.o libhyphen.la
libtool: link: gcc -g -O2 -o .libs/example example.o  ./.libs/libhyphen.so
cp -f ./hyphen.tex hyphen.us
patch < ./hyphen.patch
patching file hyphen.us
./tbhyphext.sh <./tbhyphext.tex >hyphen.us2
cat hyphen.us hyphen.us2 | mawk -f ./lig.awk >hyphen.us3
mawk: ./lig.awk: line 44: function gensub never defined
mawk: ./lig.awk: line 44: function gensub never defined
mawk: ./lig.awk: line 44: function gensub never defined
mawk: ./lig.awk: line 44: function gensub never defined
mawk: ./lig.awk: line 44: function gensub never defined
Makefile:968: recipe for target 'hyphen.us3' failed
make[1]: *** [hyphen.us3] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/santosh/hyphen-2.8.8'
Makefile:510: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

"make all-recursive" and then "make install" should resolve the issue.